# How to measure intensity (lumen) of a light source?

Tags: led, light, brightness

Let's say I have an x800 cree LED (which was supposed to be 4000lumen) and a cheap lux-meter (thinking of buying one like [this](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Tacklife-LM01-Classic-Digital-Tester-Display/dp/B01MUBTB6V/ref=sr_1_10?dchild=1&keywords=luxmeter&qid=1605970050&sr=8-10)).

My question is, which is the physical setup to measure the true intensity of the LED and covert it from lux to lumen?

The logic problem that I have is that not all the light of the LED will hit the sensor. Most will be "wasted" since the LED produces such a large circle of light, while the sensor is only a few centimeters in diameter.
How to I take into account this "wasted" light?
The formula is simple: 1 lx = 1 lm/m2, but that's obviously valid only when ALL the light from the LED hits the sensor.

There are calculators online but they ignore that most of the light is lost (does not hit the sensor). I guess they are fore measuring the light intensity on a surface, not the light intensity of the source.

Can that device be used to measure the intensity of the LED. I will gladly accept a 20% tolerance.

I never before measured brightness of a light source. As you can see, I have no clue what I talking about. So, I could be wrong in every possible way. I apologize for my newbie question.

Comment: Data sheet for the LED? Data sheet / manual for the meter? Original manufacturer's site for the meter? Have you checked the customer reviews of the meter?

Comment: @Andyaka - Neeeh... my question is not about the LED itself (or the measurement device), but about the measurement process. If I understand it, I could apply it on other things also. So, my question is how would you measure such system? What do you take into account? How you compensate for "lost" light, etc  :)

Comment: @Andyaka-I changed the title from LED to light-source.

Comment: Then assume that the light source is isotropic and that you actually know the measurement sensitivity area of the meter and do some simple maths. Or assume that the light source is actually that produced by the LED you are talking about and read the data sheet to find out about it's emission angle and do more complex math.

Comment: You are still asking questions about the meter (such as this: Can that device be used to measure the intensity of the LED) that require a data sheet or manual of the meter. So, if you don't want to provide the information adjust your question to present the reader with the details needed.